# Trying to restrict access to a particular node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to restrict access to a particular node (NOT node type) in Drupal.

I'm not finding a good module to be able to do this (or I am not understanding how to).

It seems like Content Access might be a good one - but I see no way to make access to a specific node not be granted.

How is the best way to restrict access to one particular node in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

[Node Access](http://drupal.org/project/node_access) should do the trick

> Provides global and **node specific** security permissions by role and user account.
>
> - Global security for all content types and nodes (default).
> - Per content type and all nodes for the content type.
> - **Per node security scheme**

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

The [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module is indeed a good one.

After installing and enabling, go to `Home › Administer › Content management` and select the content type you're interested in.  Click `Edit` and then the `Access control` tab.  Look at the bottom of the page at the panel `Per content node access control settings`.

When you enable this a new tab for the content access settings appears when viewing content, allowing controlling access for each individual node.

If you're looking for even more fine-grained per node access control, take a look at [Flexi Access](http://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess) (however it is currently for Drupal 7 only).  It is set up to control access per node by default, and also let you create and maintain access control lists, breaking access control down to both per user and per node.

I am using both of these myself, and they work.

For more options, see the page: [Overview of Node Access modules](http://drupal.org/node/270000) @ Drupal.org.